# Error installing/initiating pgadmin4 SQLAlchemy 1.1.0 or greater is required

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy, pgadmin-4

i'm installing pgadmin4 in Mint 19, following this instructions:

https://linuxhint.com/install-pgadmin4-ubuntu/

When i come to run:

```
https://linuxhint.com/install-pgadmin4-ubuntu/
```

I have an error:

```
File "/home/nico/pgadamin4/pgAdmin4/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/util/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    raise CommandError("SQLAlchemy 1.1.0 or greater is required. ")
alembic.util.exc.CommandError: SQLAlchemy 1.1.0 or greater is required
```

at this point, i don't know how to proceed. I don't really understand the whole installing process, using the virtual environment, so i can't add more information. Anyone can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Why are you doing it manually?

pgAdmin4 now comes as native linux package.
Goto postgres site, Select your Ubuntu version as "**Ubuntu Bionic**" (which your Linux mint is based on).

> https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

Add postgres repo as show on above link, and then do

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pgadmin4

Comment: doesn't seem to work anymore https://askubuntu.com/a/1230574/471881

Answer (score 0):

For pgAdmin 4 v4.21 on Ubuntu, according to the download page:

Install dependencies, create a virtual environment, download, install & configure
Using Python2.x

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenv python-pip libpq-dev python-dev

cd
virtualenv pgadmin4
cd pgadmin4
source bin/activate

pip install https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v4.21/pip/pgadmin4-4.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

**Using Python3.6 (Preferred to avoid encoding related issues)**

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenv python3-pip libpq-dev python3-dev

cd
virtualenv -p python3 pgadmin4
cd pgadmin4
source bin/activate

pip3 install https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v4.21/pip/pgadmin4-4.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

**Configure**
Override default paths and set it to single-user mode in the local configuration file:

```
nano lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config_local.py
```

For Python3.x:

```
nano lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/config_local.py
```

Write:

```
import os
DATA_DIR = os.path.realpath(os.path.expanduser(u'~/.pgadmin/'))
LOG_FILE = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'pgadmin4.log')
SQLITE_PATH = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'pgadmin4.db')
SESSION_DB_PATH = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'sessions')
STORAGE_DIR = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'storage')
SERVER_MODE = False
```

Run

```
python lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

For Python3.x:

```
python3 lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

Access

```
Access at http://localhost:5050
```

Exit

```
Exit with Ctrl-C
```

**Run again**

```
cd ~/pgadmin4
source bin/activate
python lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

For Python3.6

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/pgadmin4
source bin/activate
python3 lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

**Make a shortcut**

```
touch ~/pgadmin4/pgadmin4
chmod +x ~/pgadmin4/pgadmin4
nano ~/pgadmin4/pgadmin4
```

Write:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/pgadmin4
source bin/activate
python lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

For Python3.6

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/pgadmin4
source bin/activate
python3 lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

Now you can just run it with a simpler command:

```
~/pgadmin4/pgadmin4
```

**Python3 users**
Replace [x] in Python3.6 with your respective version.

**Conflict with pgAdmin 3 configuration**
pgAdmin 4 will not start in the environment where pgAdmin 3 was previously installed and used because of incompatible configuration in the .pgadmin directory. The simplest solution is to either clear that directory or tweak config_local.py to point to a clean new .pgadmin4 directory.